# Elastic Canvas date formatting

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to format date in a Kibana Canvas, so I followed this documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-canvas-data-table-and-debug-elements

But the example is fails, using:

`| mapColumn Time fn={ date | formatdate “hh:mm A” }`

replace my columns with current date but not query result date.

Someone have the good way to format date?

Here is the full expression:

```
filters
| essql 
  query="SELECT 
MAX(\"occurred\") AS MAX_DATE_TIME,
MIN(\"occurred\") AS MIN_DATE_TIME
FROM \"elastic_reports_index\""
| mapColumn "MIN_DATE_TIME" fn={date | formatdate "DD/MM/YYYY"}
| mapColumn "MAX_DATE_TIME" fn={date | formatdate "DD/MM/YYYY"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and had to use `getCell` (taken from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/canvas-does-not-recognize-date-field/127095/6).

Try:

```
| mapColumn "MIN_DATE_TIME" fn={getCell MIN_DATE_TIME | formatdate "DD/MM/YYYY"}
| mapColumn "MAX_DATE_TIME" fn={getCell MAX_DATE_TIME | formatdate "DD/MM/YYYY"}
```